# java illegal character error, how to fix?

Tags: intellij-idea, compiler-errors, character, illegal-characters

I have tried changing the encoding type, does not seem to help, only occurs when trying to build

Screenshots:

[image: Error]

If you notice, all errors are on the first line. That is not all the errors, but its the same for every class. The first line is package declaration.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the actual code being executed

Comment: Check the encoding: http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/03/use-the-utf-8-luke-file-encodings-in-intellij-idea/.

Comment: The encoding is utf16, but I tried changing it to other encodings also, and for the code that is erroring: package somepackage;

Comment: the package was not named somepackage but it was plain text